# Signup/login with facebook node js api

Tags: node.js, react-native, express, facebook

I've building an api backend for a mobile app built with react-native. And mobile developer has provided a json data file by mobile developer with the following data format.

```
{
  "firstName": "John",
  "imageURL": "https:link-to-image.com/file.jpg",
  "lastName": "Joe",
  "linkURL": null,
  "middleName": null,
  "name": "John Doe",
  "userID": "1234567890"
}
```

He's using `react native fbsdk next` in react-native to get user information from facebook.

I have the following routes setup:

**auth.js**

```
router.post(
  "/facebook/signup",
  [
    body("facebookUserId")
      .not()
      .isEmpty()
      .withMessage("Facebook user id is required"),
    body("name").not().isEmpty().withMessage("Name is required"),
  ],
  controller.userRegisterWithFacebook
);

router.post(
  "/facebook/login",
  [
    body("facebookUserId")
      .not()
      .isEmpty()
      .withMessage("Facebook user id is required"),
  ],
  controller.loginWithFacebook
);
```

And my controller:

```
exports.userRegisterWithFacebook = async (req, res, next) => {
  const { facebookUserId, name } = req.body;
  try {
    validateRequest(req);
    const user = await User.findOne({ facebookUserId: facebookUserId });
    if (user) {
      res
        .status(422)
        .json({ message: "User already registered. Please login." });
    }
    const newUser = new User({
      name: name,
      facebookUserId: facebookUserId,
    });

     await newUser.save();

    res.status(200).json({
      message: "User registered successfully with facebook."
    });
  } catch (err) {
    if (!err.statusCode) {
      err.statusCode = 500;
    }
    next(err);
  }
};

exports.loginWithFacebook = async (req, res, next) => {
  const { facebookUserId } = req.body;
  try {
    validateRequest(req);
    const user = await User.findOne({ facebookUserId: facebookUserId });
    if (!user) {
      res.status(422).json({ message: "User not found" });
    }
    const token = await jwt.sign(
      {
        facebookUserId: user.facebookUserId,
        userId: user._id.toString(),
      },
      process.env.SECRET_KEY,
      {
        expiresIn: "1h",
      }
    );

    res.status(200).json({
      message: "Logged in success",
      token: token,
      userData: {
        ...user._doc,
        password: null,
        _id: user._id.toString(),
      },
    });
  } catch (err) {
    if (!err.statusCode) {
      err.statusCode = 500;
    }
    next(err);
  }
};
```

But I'm not quite sure if this is the correct way of implementing facebook login in Node.js api for mobile apps.

If anyone figure outs the route and required parameters it can be exploited fake data.
What is the best way to implement facebook login for mobile apps with Node.js backend ?

Comment: Send only the access token from the client to the server; then use the access token on the server side, to request the user details via API.

Answer (score 0):

> But I'm not quite sure if this is the correct way of implementing
> facebook login in nodejs api for mobile apps.

Yes, this is not a correct way of login using FB. You can use OAuth to do it. There are several packages out there to implement it.

What you are doing is local authentication using Facebook id only. It is not facebook login. You need to follow some simple steps to achieve it.

You should follow [this](https://codeforgeek.com/facebook-login-using-nodejs-express/) link, it has step-by-step way to implement it.

Comment: I have a question.
Is it ok to remove use of `react native fbsdk next` from `react-native` If i use `passport` and `passport-facebook` on backend ?

Comment: Yes, you can do it too. It depends how are you making the flow of the authentication. I believe if you use the react native fbsdk you can directly use the token and make the authentication in the app and you don't need the backend API.  If that suits the app you can only use react native fbsdk else create the Node.js API and do authentication there.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who are having similar issue, this is how I got it working:

1. `react native fbsdk next` react-native package will get get `facebookUserId` and `authToken` from facebook application
2. Pass received data `facebookUserId` and `authToken` to backend
3. Validate `authToken` and `facebookUserId` from facebook graph api and get  required data and save in db

   ```
   exports.userRegisterWithFacebook = async (req, res, next) => {
     const { facebookUserId, authToken } = req.body;
     try {
       validateRequest(req);
       const user = await User.findOne({ facebookUserId: facebookUserId });
       if (user) {
         res
           .status(422)
           .json({ message: "User already registered. Please login." });
       }
       let response = await axios.get(
         `https://graph.facebook.com/${facebookUserId}? 
               fields=id,name,email,picture&access_token=${authToken}`
       );
       if (response.status !== 200) {
             res.status(422).json({ message: "Invalid facebook user id or token" });
       }
       const newUser = new User({
         facebookUserId: response.data.id,
         name: response.data.name,
         email: response.data.email,
         profileImg: response.data.picture.data.url,
       });

   await newUser.save();

   res.status(200).json({
     message: "User registered successfully with facebook.",
   });
     } catch (err) {
       if (!err.statusCode) {
         err.statusCode = 500;
       }
      next(err);
     }
   };
   ```